# phpmyadmin add Zero before all value for mobile no

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to fix some mobile no entry using phpmyadmin's SQL box.

Current mobile no  format: 174254875444 (zero missing)

expected mobile no: 0174254875444

What I've tried

```
UPDATE `client_entry`
SET `contact_no` = "0" + `contact_no`;
```

But its not working. What would be the way to add 0 before all values on `contact_no` column?

Comment: Whats the data type?

Comment: data type Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mysql use `concat`

```
UPDATE `client_entry` SET `contact_no` = concat('0' , contact_no);
```